# How can I share a folder from the terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-share, terminal

I have Ubuntu installed with no gui running as a web server. How can I share folders over the network without the gui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up Samba from any PC on the LAN using SWAT via your web-browser. This is perhaps the easiest.

Alternatively, you can edit the Samba configuration file with a text editor and restart the Samba services.

A good start is to read the documentation at http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/ - there are some HOWTO documents which ought to be worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

you want access from windows or linux

https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/internet/C/networking-shares.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how to "share folders over the network". Just to throw in a bunch:

- smb
- nfs
- ftp
- webdav
- sshfs
- ...

I'd say it mostly depends on OS (windows or unix-type), the network connection (direct access via LAN, nat-ed, VPN-solution) of the client machine and if you want to permanently serve files or not.

For example for one-time access to some files from a linux box i like to use sshfs which doesn't really need any configuration on the server except a running sshd. For permanent access from Windows boxes smb is probably the way to go.

But dispite all above, any filesharing method known to me is configurable without any sort of gui ...

So, it's up to you - check your needs ...